# Do browsers support certificate transparency?

Tags: google-chrome, ssl, ssl-certificate, certificate-transparency

The google's certificate transparency project has been in place for some time, google chrome and mozilla firefox have both claimed to have joined the project, but how do I test if the browser actually suports certificate transparency and the three ways of delivery of SCT?

Answer (score 1):

One of the easiest ways to test whether a browser is checking certificate transparency is to try a known bad site, such as https://invalid-expected-sct.badssl.com. Using this address, Chrome 69 will say the site is insecure, but Safari 12.0 which doesn't perform certificate transparency will let it through.

Chrome's policy can be found at https://github.com/chromium/ct-policy/blob/master/ct_policy.md

Apple are in the process of enforcing certificate transparency with I believe the plan being to roll it out in iOS 12.1.1 and macOS 10.14.2. Their policy can be found at https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT205280

Firefox 63.0.1 doesn't seem to support certificate transparency either although support is built into Firefox I believe it is currently not enforced until some other issues are resolved.

In terms of trying to test the three methods of delivery there is a research project at https://www.ida.liu.se/~nikca89/papers/pam18.html with code available that pulls SCTs for a given list of domains so you should be able to use that to check all 3 ways. To get it working you create a file `top-1m.csv` with entries for each domain on separate lines prefixed with an ignored numeric value and execute the `main` function in `FirstTestCase`. Alternatively you could look at the [Conscrypt](https://github.com/google/conscrypt) project although that is more work.

Comment: Certificate in invalid-expected-sct.badssl.com expired couple weeks after this question was answered. Unfortunately badssl.com cannot get a replacement, see https://github.com/chromium/badssl.com/issues/372 about that.

Comment: Seems the replacement would be https://missing-sct.badssl.com however there are other SSL issues with that site currently. Once resolved and testable I'll update this answer

Comment: It's now https://no-sct.badssl.com/